# React Admin Display API response

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am new to reach admin. So, I have an api call that return response like below.

{
"data": {
"type": "someType",
"id": "userid",
"attributes": {
"credit": 0
}
}
}

I am trying to display the response on an website page. This the code i am using to diplay:

```
            <ReferenceManyField addLabel={false} reference="someType" target="users">
                <SingleFieldList linkType={false}>
                    <TextField source='credit' label='User ID' />
                </SingleFieldList>
            </ReferenceManyField>
```

Error: The response to 'getManyReference' must be like { data : [...] }, but the received data is not an array. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'getManyReference'

So, My response is not a array of collection.

Comment: Can you show us your DataProvider code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

**1. Change the API Response, if you have control over the API code**

Make the response return an array for the `data` field like:
{"data": [.....]}

**2. Convert the API response to the above format clientside after you receive it**
If you can't change the API code then just modify the format of the data into what you need it to be on the client.

Comment: Thank you @Azarro Is there any field that parse the API response and just display the data instead of changing the API response?. Like <SimpleShowLayout> or <show> I tried <ReferenceField> and it dosen't work.

Comment: Have you tried using `SimpleShowLayout`? It actually seems like that could work with TextFields in it